# Extract image url from HTML code using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pulling information from a Page note from the Facebook API. In the output I get an image URL embeded in HTML code. How can I extract the image url from the HTML code below using Javascript?

```
<img class=\"photo_img img\" src=\"http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/373909_207177302696060_189175211162936_438410_6588114253_a.jpg\" alt=\"\" />
```

**UPDATE**

The above image tag is embedded in the JSON-response from the Facebook API.
I am also using Appcelerator to create an iOS app.

**UPDATE 2**

I solved it with:

```
json.data[i].message.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1]
```

Thankful for all help!

Comment: You would need to use Regular Expression or some kind of String parsing to obtain the URL. Are you familiar with those?

Comment: No, sorry only by name. Do you know the correct syntax for this?

Comment: This is a very simple one compare to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645945/how-to-get-image-url-from-html-string-using-regex) . But It extracts the URL including double quotes, so I add `.slice(1, -1)` after the Regex rule like `String.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1].slice(1,-1)` And It works perfect now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery to extract any data from html. Use the following code

```
$(function() {
  $('img').attr("src");
});
```

This will return you the src value only for the first instance of the img tag. If you want a specific img tag, you can include it inside a div.

Comment: How can you know that he is using jquery?

Answer (score 4):

Ofcourse you can pull out these data using DOM. But question is is how many img tags would be there? or can you give some id's for this tags?

`return document.getElementById(id).src;` will do it, if it has an id.

or else, you might need to take  the img tag array using `getElementsByTagname('img')`

If its a single `img` tag, then its easy with this. You can go for a second level class matching also.

Comment: This does not work: var imgObj = json.data[i].message.getElementsByTagName('img');

Comment: But the output is HTML code. Isn´t there a way of extracting the src of the img tag?

Comment: Are you sure about applying DOM in JSON mesages?.Its a string right? I would consider loading it using DOMParser or ActiveXobject as an XML document. Then its easy to find the node using XML parsing and XPath with attribute as class name; After obtaining the Node, you can extract any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this

```
var imgObj = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
alert(imgObj.getAttribute('src'));
```

**Update**

If you are able to use jQuery, you can do the following

```
// select all images with the class 'photo_img'
var elements = $('img .photo_img').attr('src');
```

You could iterate through elements with a loop or jQuery's each function.

Comment: This does not work: var imgObj = json.data[i].message.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

Comment: i never suggested you to add it to your JSON object. I thought it was renderd html page, but now i see you have updatet your question.

Comment: Yes sorry. I have updated my question. But is there a way, using regex, to extract the src of the img tag?