# How to get image url from html string using regex

Tags: html, regex, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to get  from html string using regex which I am currently working on was this :

```
extension String {
func regex (pattern: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let nsstr = self as NSString
        let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstr.length)
        var matches : [String] = [String]()
        regex.enumerateMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
            (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
            if let r = result {
                let result = nsstr.substringWithRange(r.range) as String
                matches.append(result)
            }
        }
        return matches
    } catch {
        return [String]()
    }
}
```

And the pattern is : `<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\']([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>`

I still can't get the image url from it which mean it return me empty array.Actually my html string include one image.I don't want to use`UIWebView` because of `UITableView` resizing problem.So,I need to fetch the image url out of html and show it in UIImageView using AlamofireImage.

Any Help?It was just one url that i need to fetch.

Here is my tag :

```
<img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png"/>
```

To :

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png
```

Comment: Happy to look at this.  Can you provide the URL that you want to get this result from?

Comment: I have edited the question.Have a look

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Description

```regex
<img\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=['"]([^"]*)['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- This regex captures the entire IMG tag
- Places the source attribute value into capture group 1, without quotes if they exist.
- Allow attributes to have single, double or no quotes
- Can be modified to validate any number of other attributes
- Avoid difficult edge cases which tend to make parsing HTML difficult

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/qW9nG8/1

**Sample text**

Note the difficult edge case in the first line where we are looking for a specific droid.

```html
<img onmouseover=' if ( 6 > 3 { funSwap(" src="NotTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpg", 6 > 3 ) } ; ' src="http://website/ThisIsTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="jihgfedcba" data-imagesize="ppew" />
some text

<img src="http://website/someurl.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" />
more text
<img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png"/>
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 0 gets the entire IMG tag
- Capture group 1 gets just the src attribute value

```
[0][0] = <img onmouseover=' funSwap(" src='NotTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpg", data-pid) ; ' src="http://website/ThisIsTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-pid="jihgfedcba" data-imagesize="ppew" />
[0][1] = http://website/ThisIsTheDroidYourLookingFor.jpeg

[1][0] = <img src="http://website/someurl.jpeg" onload="img_onload(this);" />
[1][1] = http://website/someurl.jpeg

[2][0] = <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png"/>
[2][1] = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <img                     '<img'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    src=                     'src='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]                     any character of: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: From regex101.com, the equivalent string to use in PHP `preg_match_all()` is: `'/<img\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=[\'"]([^"]*)[\'"]?)(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?> /mix'` (single quotes escaped)

Answer (score 8):

This is the regex pattern you should use:

> (http[^\s]+(jpg|jpeg|png|tiff)\b)

Translation:

- Find everything that starts with "http"
- No white spaces allowed
- Ends with one of the following jpg, jpeg, png, tiff

Regex function:

```
func matches(for regex: String!, in text: String!) -> [String] {    
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var matched = matches(for: "(http[^\\s]+(jpg|jpeg|png|tiff)\\b)", in: String(htmlStr))
```

Note:

- *matched* returns as an array with matching string objects
- This code was written for Swift 3

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight tweak to the pattern give me this:

```
let string = "some text and other text <img src=\"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png\"/>;and then more text and more text"

let matches = string.regex("<img[^>]+src*=\".*?\"['/']>")
```

returns an array with the match.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 Elegant solution to extract image, audio, video `src` from htmlString

```
let filesList = matches(for: "src=\"(.*?)\"", in: htmlString)
for j in 0..<filesList.count {
    var fileName = filesList[j].replacingOccurrences(of: "src=", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
    fileName = fileName.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
}
```

where `htmlString` is String variable.