# Not able to get UIImage while downloading image. completionHandler(.notcompleted) getting called after guard let img = UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiimage

```
func downloadImage(urlStr : String , completionHandler : @escaping (DownloadImage) -> Void) {
    
    completionHandler(.serviceStarts)

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else {
            completionHandler(.notcompleted)
            return
        }
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            guard let dt = data else{
                completionHandler(.notcompleted)
                return
            }
            guard let img = UIImage(data: dt) else {
                completionHandler(.notcompleted)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(.successful(img))
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

enum DownloadImage {
    
    case serviceStarts
    case notcompleted
    case successful(UIImage)
}
```

Comment: You are receiving any data?

Comment: Yes, the url to check is url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/yC-Yzbqy7PY"

Comment: data received ->
(lldb) po dt
▿ 209905 bytes
  - count : 209905
  ▿ pointer : 0x00007fe778050000
    - pointerValue : 140632127766528

(lldb)

Comment: Try to print this ```String(data: dt, encoding: .utf8)``` and see. whether it's received image data or anything else?

Comment: Question is you are receiving UIImage data or full webpage data? this is an api to retrieve this image?

Comment: I am getting HTMl code on printing String(data: dt, encoding: .utf8).

Comment: @ReinierMelian getting full webpage data.

Comment: Then this is not image data so it will never return an image.

Comment: Well now you know why is not working you are receiving full html page

Comment: Yes I believe so as content type is showing text/html and thanks for the support. But how do i extract image from this as one company asked me to download image from an API and in response i am getting this url.

Comment: You can get all the image's URL by passing HTML string to this function and then downloading the image from the image url. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38705128/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan thanks man, it works!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.